# Переименовать подкаталоги написав их названия транслитом

Tags: c#, файлы

Переименовать все подкаталоги (в том числе и вложенные) написав их названия транслитом.

````
     ```string dirName = "C:\\";

        if (Directory.Exists(dirName))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Подкаталоги:");
            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(dirName);
            foreach (string s in dirs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }```
````

Comment: Что именно вам не понятно, как каталог переименовывать или как обойти каталоги рекурсивно?

Comment: именно как переименовать на транслит

Comment: думаю вот это вам может помочь https://gist.github.com/milovidov983/ab13405fee3e1c8e24fda1e03d73f9bd